# Error Cannot match any routes when navigating using data-toggle ="tab" in angular 6

Tags: angular

I am trying to migrate from angular js to angular 6.In angular js i have code

```
  <a data-target="#Test" data-toggle="tab">Test</a></li>
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="Test">
```

There are 4 such tabs and in angular 6 i have the code:

```
    <li class="active"><a href="#Test" [ngClass]="{ 'active':activeTab==='Test'}" (click)="Test('Test')" data-toggle="tab">Test</a></li>
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="Test" [ngClass]="{ 'active':activeTab==='Test'}">
    //component.ts
    activeTab = 'Test';


    Test(activeTab){
    this.activeTab = activeTab;
    }
```

I am referring to [Change active bootstrap tab inside angular component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51105507/change-active-bootstrap-tab-inside-angular-component)  but I am getting error Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'Test'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'Test'.

I dont understand what is going wrong, routes should not be needed for tabs. Thanks in advance

Comment: You are getting this error because of  <a href="#Test" . Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40498333/angular2-how-to-navigate-to-certain-section-of-the-page-identified-with-an-id-at

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 How to navigate to certain section of the page identified with an id attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40498333/angular2-how-to-navigate-to-certain-section-of-the-page-identified-with-an-id-at)

Comment: I have to use tabs and when i click on routerLink="policies" i get the same error. @SamarthSaxena