# nav tabs bootstrap 5 - How to @import two files inside node_modules?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a project with Angular and I'm trying to use a nav-tab. I've installed bootstrap with NPM and I have all the files inside of node_modules. To start my project I wrote in my main styles.css files the next line:

@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

After that, i could use a lot of styles but, with the nav-tabs it doesn't work (doesn't change the content and tabs), I saw that importing the bootstrap.blunde.min.js by a  tag the nav class works. So I tried to import the file by:

@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js';

And it doesn't work, the angular project just stop working so, I don't know what to do to not use the .

Someone knows if i have to install something else by NPM or do something especial? The  tag just works if I use the bootstrap tag with integrity and crossorigin, if i tried to use  and select the file inside my project, doesn't works to.

I hope you guys could help me.

Comment: Give a look at [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51105507/change-active-bootstrap-tab-inside-angular-component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51105507/change-active-bootstrap-tab-inside-angular-component). Maybe this could make your tab works without the need of changing your import at styles.